# linea de codigo bucle while

Tags: python

Estoy iniciandome en python y quisera saber los pasos de esta linea de codigo, alguien me puede orientar el paso a paso para llegar a ese resultado

```
print('While controlado por conteo')
print('===============================')
print('Sumador numero hasta 30')
sum=1
num=1
while (sum<=30):
  sum=num+sum
  num=num+1
  print('La suma es ' +str(sum))
```

---

```
While controlado por conteo
===============================
Sumador numero hasta 30
La suma es 2
La suma es 4
La suma es 7
La suma es 11
La suma es 16
La suma es 22
La suma es 29
La suma es 37
```

Comment: Se inicializa  la variable sum/num = 1. Entro En el bucle `while` que se ejecutara tantas veces como haga falta hasta que suma sea menor o igual que 30. **Primera**  vuelta : `suma` = suma(1) + num(1)  resultado : 2,  a  `num` le sumo 1.  imprimo el 2  .  **Segunda** vuelta : `sum` = num(2) + sum(2) . **Tercera** vuelta : `sum`= num(3) + sum(4).  Asi hasta que sum sea igual o menor que 30.

Comment: Tambien añadir que `sum` es un modulo de python built-in (es decir, una función que ya viene instalada por defecto en todas las instalaciones de python) y te aconsejaría no usar ese nombre de variable. Para esta prueba de concepto no hay ningun problema, pero si quisieras avanzar y decidieras usar ese módulo tendrias problemas porque habrias sobreescrito la definición. `suma = 1` seria perfectamente valido en su lugar

Answer (score 0):

while es una forma de crear bucles, se ejecuta mientras se cumple la condición.

1. Al principio se inicializan dos variables sum y num, ambas con valor 1.
2. Después viene el bucle while:

   - sum: tomará el valor de num + sum, como las inicializamos anteriormente en 1, ahora será 2
   - num: tomará el valor de num + 1, como la incializamos anteriormente en 1, ahora será 2.
   - realizamos el print que será el valor de sum en la primera iteración (que es en la que estamos) y por tanto será 2.
3. En la siguiente iteración ya los valores de sum y num han cambiado a 2, debido a la iteración primera. por lo que se repetirá la operación de arriba pero con los nuevos valores y así hasta que la variable **sum** sea menor o igual a 30.
4. Tu duda entiendo que puede estar motivada por dos factores:

   - ¿Por qué sum y num no vuelven a ser 1?: porque no están dentro del bucle, una vez inicializadas las variables sum y num con valor 1, se introducen las operaciones en el bucle y while siempre recive el valor de sum y de num de la última iteración del bucle
   - ¿Por qué se imprime 37 si es mayor que 30?: el print está al final del bucle, por tanto recibe los valores asignados por while una vez finalizada la iteración. Teniendo esto en cuenta.

     1. Se finaliza la penultima iteración en la que sum tiene el valor 29. al ser menor que 30 se inicial la última iteración.
     2. En la última iteración se realizan las operaciones y después se imprime su resultado, que es 37, como ya es mayor que 30, no se realiza ninguna operación más.

Answer (score 0):

**Paso a paso**

*inicialización de variables del bucle*

```
sum=1
num=1
```

Ambas tomarán el valor 1 y se trabajará con ellas en el bucle, cabe recordar que la variable sum es la que, mediante el cambio de su valor, terminará la ejecución del bucle while.

*Bucle while*

```
while (sum<=30):
     sum=num+sum
     num=num+1
     print('La suma es ' +str(sum))
```

Primero se comprueba que sum sea menor o igual a 30 y si es así, se ejecutará las instrucciones dentro del bucle.

La variable sum ahora será igual a la suma de su valor más el valor que tiene la variable num. (Primera iteración: sum = 1 + 1)

La variable se irá incrementando en 1 cada vez que se ejecute el bucle. `num=num+1` sería lo mismo que poner `num++`

Finalmente se ejecutará `print('La suma es ' +str(sum))`, que imprimirá por pantalla el resultado de cada iteración, `str(sum)` se utiliza para imprimir la variable `sum` como `string`.

**Resumen**

El bucle trabaja con dos variables, `num` y `sum`, dicho bucle finalizará cuando la variable `sum` sea igual a 30 o superior.
En cara iteración la variable `sum` será igual a la suma de su valor y `num`, `num` se incrementará en 1 y se imprimirá por pantalla los resultados de la variable `sum`.